# Perevent sendind certain trigger to telegram

Tags: triggers, notifications, telegram, webhooks, zabbix

How can I prevent telegram from sending certain zabbix trigger?
I wan prevent sending certain trigger (problem) to telegram.
How I can perform this in zabbix?

Answer (score 1):

You should manage [actions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/it/manual/config/notifications/action) and their [conditions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/notifications/action/conditions)

The most basic action will send a message via all media to a specific user: you can modify this behavior with conditions, for instance to send to a specific user via email for lesser alert, then via telegram for High or Critical triggers.

You can also use tags, host, host groups etc: see the full [conditions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/notifications/action/conditions) list

Also consider that a specific user will receive only the alerts for hosts which he has read permission: you can filter on this as well.